# Retrieve file from firebase storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I bet it's something very trivial, but even the docs arent clear about this. I don't have to mention that writing anything about firebase in google search returns topics that are related not with JS/WEB but with android in most cases...

The case is that I have a storage folder `images` that holds... images. I would like to retrieve it when entering my site. My try:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const images = firebase.storage().ref().child('companyImages');
  const image = images.child('image1');        <----------------    // file name is image1
  image.on('value', (snap) => this.setState({ img: snap.val() }));
}
```

However it doesnt work as I suppose it to do. As u can see I would like to store this image in state and then display in some part of my site.

Looking forward for any hints etc.
Thank u :)

Comment: this line `const images = firebase.storage().ref().child('companyImages');` doesn't retrieve data from firebase?

Comment: @KenrySanchez It returns an object with two keys: `authWrapper` and `location`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no method `on()` in the [Firebase Storage SDK for the Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference). You're probably confusing it with the [`on("value"` method in the Firebase Database SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on).

To [download data from Cloud Storage in your Firebase web app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files), you [get the download URL for the file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) and then use that (typically in your HTML) to get the data.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const images = firebase.storage().ref().child('companyImages');
  const image = images.child('image1');
  image.getDownloadURL().then((url) => { this.setState({ img: url }));
}
```