# How get file in firebase from firebase storage from localhost server?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

How get file in firebase from firebase storage from localhost server?

It's about a local react-app server that wants to have access to firebase storage on a Google server.  `@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/pHLJj11vpJeQHtOHuYHD1wVtm203 failed: permission_denied`

I have not found an answer to it anywhere.
Is it possible?

Comment: I think I **[`found it`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045366/retrieve-file-from-firebase-storage)** for you..

Comment: Take a look here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup, and gsutil https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil.

Comment: @user110210121 I think I wrote wrong. It's about a local react-app server that wants to have access to firebase storage on a Google server.  ` @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/pHLJj11vpJeQHtOHuYHD1wVtm203 failed: permission_denied `