# How to display Firebase Storage download URLS in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, user-interface, url, firebase-storage

I am trying to display a list of all the download URLS of my files that I have in my firebase console. I am able to log them to the console and see them, but I cannot figure out how to access them and display them on the UI. I am trying to return them to the UI in the return statement of my my displayFile function. Most examples I have seen online are for images, but I am primarily storing documents. I'm that potentially has to do with it as i'm not able to make an img tag and set the src to the url. Thanks!

```
listFiles = () => {
const storage = firebase.storage().ref('files');
storage.listAll().then(function(result){
    result.items.forEach(function(fileRef) {
        displayFile(fileRef);
        });
    }).catch(function(error){
        //handle any errors TODO
    })

function displayFile(fileRef){
    fileRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        //console.log(url);
        //return file URLS
        return(
            <ul>
                <li>
                    {url}
                </li>
            </ul>
        )

    }).catch(function(error) {
        //TODO
    })
}
}
```

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/kqeaqm/how_to_display_firebase_storage_download_urls_in/

Comment: Anything that is loaded asynchronously will need to be stored in the state and rendered from there. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045366/retrieve-file-from-firebase-storage/48046146#48046146 for an example