# Get only one item from firebase storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to build a website to develop my skills. I try to do something but I couldn't find a solution.

```
import { getStorage, ref, listAll } from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();

// Create a reference under which you want to list
const listRef = ref(storage, 'files/uid');

// Find all the prefixes and items.
listAll(listRef)
  .then((res) => {
    res.prefixes.forEach((folderRef) => {
      // All the prefixes under listRef.
      // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
    });
    res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
      // All the items under listRef.
    });
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  });
```

on the Firebase Storage documentation, I can see how to get all prefixes and files. What I want to do is to get only one item from the folder. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you know the name of the file you want to get, you can go straight to https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

Comment: I know the folder names, and I want to get only one item from the folder. I try to build a basic e-commerce website, and all products has their own Storage folders. Inside those folders, I have products photos.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve file from firebase storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045366/retrieve-file-from-firebase-storage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: `listAll` only retrieves the file names, not the data from those files.*

There is no way to get a list of only one filename in a folder through the API. I'd recommend either giving that first file a default name, like `default.jpg` so that you can use that name in your code, or only retrieving the first file that `listAll` gives you.

Comment: I will try this. You usually try to help me for my Firebase problems. Thank you very much.